# Get width of div with columns

Tags: jquery, dom, css, javascript

I have a simple markup

```
.content{
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    width : 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
​
<div class="content">
Much text so the text will extend the box...
<div/>
```

When I use jQuerys width function it always return 200 which is wrong, or at least not what I expected.

I need to measure the width of the div with class content and it has a lot of text inside, that will extend the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/EJEsP/

Comment: `width : 200px;` , so why you think its wrong ?

Comment: Have a look at the example, the content have many lines and extend the div.

Comment: errr? what were u expecting? the css has `width : 200px`

Comment: Its width is 200px but content overflows the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.content{
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    width : 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
#wrapper {
    width : auto;
}


<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    Many lines
    <div/>
<div/>

alert($("#wrapper").width())​
```

Insert your content into another div with width:auto and get that div's width with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, exaclty what I serached for!

Comment: +1 for simplicity. i withdraw my answer in favor of this one.

Answer (score 0):

You get it, because your content is really 200px width.

Comment: Yeah in the stackoverflow example, but not in the fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the width

see updated example

http://jsfiddle.net/EJEsP/2/

Comment: It will break the columns if I remove the div

Comment: maybe you want to set the -webkit-column-width to 200px? http://jsfiddle.net/EJEsP/7/

Answer (score 0):

You've set you're width to 200px. No matter whats inside that div won't be seen as bigger unless you add them within another div. change the width to be auto and see if that's more what you were expecting :)

http://jsfiddle.net/EJEsP/5/

Comment: Yeah it solves the problem, but the columns is breaked if i remove the width.

Comment: breaked as it's 4 rather than 3? that's unfortunately something you'll have to create more code for. if you increase the height to 600px you'll get 3 colomns. http://jsfiddle.net/EJEsP/8/

Comment: Yes I know, but the height is fixed. However I found a solution in gabitzish answer